# Map a route to admin/news/show and another to news/show, do I need 2 controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Actually I don't understand how to correctly handle this. I have a situation where news could be managed with admin/edit admin/show admin/news... and similar paths, however I want to give users a page called news/show/1, because actually my news resources are routed under "admin" namespace, how should I handle the fact that I need to bind news routes outside "admin" namespace?

Actually I have only this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :news
end
```

**My Idea:**

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :news
end
resources :news
```

Then I'll have:

- app/controllers/admin/news_controller.rb
- app/controllers/news_controller.rb

Is this correct?

Comment: a simple `match '/news/show/:id' => 'news#show'` dont work?

Comment: you can use single controller. but i will personally prefer separate controller.

Comment: why dont you try it? you are right..

Comment: @caarlos0: Mh because the "show" action *could* be different (dunno, maybe to check user permissions).

Comment: @HungryCoder: Yea I think it's a good thing to have separated controller, I was not sure however if could lend to bugs.

Comment: @Lichtamberg: Well I tried it, I'm asking if this is a good way to handle everything in this way. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: I get your point, so, I believe that's better separate controllers just like you said.

Comment: Thanks Caarlos, I'm still doing some tests if I'm really satisfact with controller separations. However, having a user access to a controller under "Admin" module feels a wrong, even if it's not.

Comment: @caarlos0: Mh I'm trying in this way because I don't want all resources to be routed (I don't have action for edit/new/destroy for non-admin users): `match 'news/:id(.:format)' => 'news#show', via: :get` however in this way rails doesn't create `news_path` helper. Any suggestion on how to force that helper creation? It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: add to your route: `:as => 'admin_news'`, so you can use it as `admin_news_path`, if I'm not mistaken. :)

Comment: HungryCodes suggested a good way to do this, see his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your answer, I can suggest more simpler routes.

```
#routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :news
end

resources :news, :only => [:show]
```

If you want `index` action too, rewrite the last line as:

```
resources :news, :only => [:index, :show]
```

You won't need the helper for `news_path` and `news_url`. You will get them already built for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after working a bit on routes, I understood how to build what I wanted:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :news
end

get 'news/:id(.:format)' => 'news#show'
```

This because I don't need all routes for my news, but only show (well I may add index too, but not required at the moment). In this way I can handle everything on 2 different controllers, which is better, because I use somethings like redirects on the news controller which I don't use on Admin::NewsController.

I noticed another important thing, if you build routes in this way **news_path and news_url won't be created**. Because of this, I had to manually create them in this way in news_helpers:

```
module NewsHelper
  def news_url(record)
    url_for controller: 'news', action: 'show', only_path: false, id: record.slug
  end

  def news_path(record)
    url_for controller: 'news', action: 'show', only_path: true, id: record.slug
  end
end
```

(slug is for seo-friendly urls) Then I simply included the helper in my controller in this way:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  include NewsHelper
```

Everything is worked as I wanted and looks great too.